# How to control complete model with single empty

Tags: parent

I have several empty's and i want to parent all the empty's to a new empty to control my model to rotate, scale & move. Some empty have rotation limit some have location limit. Some are just mesh without empty. I want to control my complete model so that i cant rotate scale and move. I tried to add a empty and selecting all the empty and mesh and last the new empty and parented. It do parented but working of the limit rotation and limit location not working. Any suggestion or help how it works. Thanks.

[(video)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIdmv.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

do you mean like this?

https://youtu.be/k_ks-DzSBV0

if yes:

Parenting the empty works exactly as you described.

But...
you have to change your limit rotation settings.

I just had a look at your fold constraint.

The correct setup looks like this:

[image]

You have to restrict all axis except the one you want to move (in your special case here) so just the x-Axis got some values, all others with 0 but checked.
I am not sure why it does not work if you check the lock on the axis values, but with my settings it works.